# Number of days between two columns SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I was looking for the answer to this question, and I found here that `DATEDIFF()` function is a way to do it when you have the dates. But, what if you don't have specific dates?

What if you want to find the interval of time between the date in *2 columns* (`rental_date, return_date`).

I tried to use `DATEDIFF()` function, but it looks like you need the actual date.

Comment: could you provide some sample data

Comment: You can datediff on the columns in the table as well.? Eg: select datediff(dd,rental_date,return_date) from <your_table>

Comment: Are you using timeStamp or string as rental_date and return_date ?

Comment: Just subtract them `date_column_one - date_column_two` (assuming both columns are defined as `DATE`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date_part` for finding differences between two dates in the `PostgreSQL`.

The syntax is like as follow.

```
DATE_PART('day', enddate - startdate);
```

You can get years, months, weeks, hours, minutes seconds as well. You can check more about the usage of date different and date part function in PostgreSQL by clicking on [this](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff) link.

Comment: If `enddate` and `startdate` are `DATE` values, `enddate - startdate` is enough

Answer (score 1):

if your two column data type is date then you could do subtraction

```
select '2018-12-10'::date - '2018-11-18'::date
```

so in your case it would be

```
with t1 as
(
select '2018-12-10'::date as rental_date, '2018-11-18'::date as return_date
)
select rental_date-return_date from t1
```